# error when compile lex.yy.c with g++

Tags: g++, lex

i have written a bison, flex and c++ files.
Compilation of bisoon and flex was passed. But when i'm trying to compile the c and cpp files:
g++ *.cpp *.c, i get strange error: 
lex.yy.c:479: error: expected `;' before "static"
and when i opened lex.yy.c file, i see code that was automatically created by flex. This is some part of code around line 479, line 479 is bold:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace output
#line 465 "lex.yy.c"

/* Macros after this point can all be overridden by user definitions in
 * section 1.
 */

#ifndef YY_SKIP_YYWRAP
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" int yywrap YY_PROTO(( void ));
#else
extern int yywrap YY_PROTO(( void ));
#endif
#endif

#ifndef YY_NO_UNPUT
```

**static void yyunput YY_PROTO(( int c, char *buf_ptr ));**
    #endif

```
#ifndef yytext_ptr
static void yy_flex_strncpy YY_PROTO(( char *, yyconst char *, int ));
#endif
```

i don't have any idea what to do. Please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should`t try to fix the error in file generated by lex, instead of it you need to check your lex specification for errors.

UPDATE:

Possible place to look for source of such mistake is lex specification user code section. As it is noticed in comments, LEX isn`t checking code that it generates from the specification.

Comment: i understand that i don't need to touch the lex auto-generated file, but i don't know what can be the problem. So i opened the lex.yy.c to see in what code mine or auto-generated is the problem.

Comment: It would be great to see lex specification, because it can be anything, e.g. missing semicolon in lex specification user code section.

Comment: problem is solved. I forget semicolon in lex file in one of the declarations of C code and my mistake was to think that flex compilation checks C code together with lex code.

Comment: np, I`ll add my comment contents to the answer, who knows, maybe it will help someone to solve similar problem :)